# Views Group by Different Fields

Tags: 7, views, entities

So I have a page type with a couple of different fields (each is its own field under content):
Department (Field: Department)
Office Affiliation (Content: Office Affiliation)
Center Affiliation (Content: Center Affiliation(s))

I would like to Group the members of each of these in one view, with them being grouped by their specific affiliation (whether it be Department, Office, or Center).

I currently have the view set up in a table and if I only choose one grouping (Grouping field Nr.1) it shows up fine and leaves people without that specific affiliation grouped together without a group title.

For example, by Department:
Jane Smith
John Smith

Department 1:
Jane Doe

Department 2:
John Doe

If I add a second grouping (Grouping field Nr.2) it breaks it entirely to where no names show up and the departments just list without any names in them.  Anyone know how to make this work so it's something like this?

Center Affiliation 1:
Name1

Center Affiliation 2:
Name2

Office Affiliation 1:
Name3

Office Affiliation 2:
Name4

Department 1:
Name5

Department 2:
Name6

Thanks.